# Swagger: how to use the generated json files?

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, swashbuckle

I've been provided with the json files generated by swashbuckle for a rest api I should be consuming and I was wondering if there are tools that can take those files as input and allow an easier navigation of exposes methods, request payloads, response payloads, headers, etc. Also when working in .NET is there a way or tool to generate payload classes as with wsdl documents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the swagger editor

https://editor.swagger.io/

This will allow you to view and browse the methods.  Simply paste the contents of your received JSON.

Then also, at the top of the page you have "generate client" options for different languages.  Which will generate C# (or other) langauge files for you.